# How to fix a 24fps shot that looks jerky when rendered at 30fps frame rate?

Tags: premiere, editing, effects, framerate

I accidentally shot one scene at 24fps instead of the 30fps I intended.  I want to render it at 30fps (to fit the rest of the video), but the render from Premiere looks choppy, regardless of whether I use Frame Blending or not.  I know this is expected, especially since I shot at 1/60 shutter speed, but are there any effects / settings I can apply to smooth things out?  Blur perhaps?

For what it's worth, it's a moving shot of some dancing, so both the subject and the camera are moving throughout.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with Blender? Load the video in the video editing and modify the fps in the default page. Render after that and check.

Comment: Thanks @YoMismo! It's worth a shot, especially if it interpolates motion better than Premiere's Frame Blending (does it?).  I'm concerned about loss of quality from multiple renders, though, but maybe Blender has good lossless support or its interpolation looks good enough to make losses worthwhile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the frame rate of everything to 60fps you'll get an even frame blend every 2.5 (60fps) frames.  If you change the frame rate to 120fps you can eliminate the stutter completely, as 30 fps will repeat frames 4x and 24fps will repeat frames 5x.  But few systems can play 120fps, whereas many can play 60fps (including YouTube).

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  I would not have thought of your solution.